# jQuery Password match validation - Error message doesn't hide

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

Working on a basic registration form. User is supposed to type in a password, then type it in again and as they're typing into the 'confirm password' box, it should say "passwords must match" if they don't and not show any error if they do match. It'll load with no error displayed, and it'll show the error while typing into the confirm box, but after a matching password is put in the error doesn't go away. What do I need to fix?

jQuery script:

```
$(":password").change(function(){                               
    if($("#passConfirm").val() != $("#password").val() ){
        $("#matchText").show()
    }
    else{
        $("#matchText)").hide();
        }
});
```

Relevant section of the form:

```
Password: 
<input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" >
</br>
</br>

Confirm Password: 
<input type="password" id="passConfirm" placeholder="Password" >
<span class="error" id="matchText" style="display:none;">Passwords must match.</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your code:

```
$("#matchText)").hide();
```

Should be

```
$("#matchText").hide();
```

Since the id is `#matchText` but not `#matchText)`.

Comment: Yup, that was it! If it'd been a snake and all that. Thank you! ^_^

Comment: @MKWhit You're welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted by ticking the accept button next to it when you can :)

Comment: Yup yup, it's on the docket, site just wants me to wait 10 min first.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your jQuery selector.

```
$("#matchText)").hide();
```

Should be ..

```
$("#matchText").hide();
```